# How is the height of a GridView determined, and can it be changed?

Tags: android, gridview

I have a pair of vertically-arranged GridViews that are populated with buttons by an Adapter. I can get the GridViews to fill the width of the parent view, but I can't get the second GridView to fill the height of the parent view.

It appears that the height of the GridViews is fixed and can't be changed. If there's more than enough space for the GridViews, they don't fill the parent. If there's not enough space, they go into scroll mode -- and scroll mode can't be turned off.

I'm not sure, but GridView seems to be using a fixed height for the child button views, I can't figure out how the button (row) height is determined, or how I can change it or force GridView to fill the parent height.

Here's the XML for the GridViews:

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/keypads"
                android:background="@color/keypad_background_color"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:isScrollContainer="false"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/grdMeasButtons"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:numColumns="4"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:isScrollContainer="false"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/grdNumButtons"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:isScrollContainer="false"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Note that my original version sets a height of 0px for each GridView and weight ratio of 1:2 to set the height relationship of the GridViews. That doesn't fill the parent either, and if the weight of one of the views is too small, it goes into scroll mode. The "isScrollContainer" attribute doesn't turn that off.

Here's the getView() method from the Adapter:

```
    // create a new ButtonView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Button btn;
    if ((convertView == null) || !initializing) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                // attributes

        btn = new Button(mContext);
        KeypadButton keypadButton = mButtons[position];

        switch(keypadButton.mCategory)
        {
        case NUMBER:
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.keypadnumber);
            break;
        case DECIMAL:
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.keypadnumber);
            break;
        case CLEAR:
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.keypadnumber);
            break;
        case WEIGHT:    
        case VOLUME:
            switch (unitState[position]) {
            case SELECTED:
                btn.setEnabled(true);
                btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.keypad_measure_selected);
                btn.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.units_text_enabled));
                break;
            case ENABLED:
                btn.setEnabled(true);
                btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.keypad_measure_not_selected);
                btn.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.units_text_enabled));
                break;
            case DISABLED:
                btn.setEnabled(false);
                btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.keypad_measure_not_selected);
                btn.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.units_text_disabled));
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            break;
        case DUMMY:
            break;
        default:
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.keypadnumber);
            break;
        }
        // Set OnClickListener of the button to mOnButtonClick
        if(keypadButton != KeypadButton.DUMMY)
            btn.setOnClickListener(mOnButtonClick);
        else
            btn.setClickable(false);
        // Set CalculatorButton enumeration as tag of the button so that we
        // will use this information from our main view to identify what to do
        btn.setTag(keypadButton);
    } else {
        btn = (Button) convertView;
    }

    btn.setText(mButtons[position].getText());
    return btn;
}
```

(Don't worry about the the unitState array. It solves yet another problem.)

Even when the view is being recycled, the height (and width) of the button is zero, and setting it has no effect.

Can the height or fill attributes of the GridViews or buttons be set in Layout parameters before the GridViews are populated?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Just replace your second GridView With This One
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/grdNumButtons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

Comment: As I said, my original version used "0px" for height and weights for the two GridViews, and that made no difference -- parent still not filled. Just to be sure, I tried using weight only on the second GridView and that doesn't work, either.

Answer (score 0):

If GridView not filled to parent, then you have to calculate, device Height programatically in getView() method. After calculating height of the device, set GridView's layoutParams to match parent or fill parent, it will solve your problem.

Comment: This approach sets the GridView heights correctly, but it doesn't change the button height. So if there's not enough room for the buttons, the GridView scrolls. See my post below for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by pratik was on the right track, but setting the size of the GridViews in the adapter is no different from using "fill_parent" or weighted heights on the GridViews in XML. Sure, the GridViews are set to the correct height, but the buttons are always the same size. So if a GridView isn't big enough for its buttons, the GridView scrolls. Useless for a keypad.

As I suspected, the problem is the button size. I still don't know how Android determines the button height, but it appears to fixed -- i.e., it's not dependent on the button width, which is properly adjusted to fit the GridView width. I'm guessing this is a bug in GridView. It also seems to be a bug that you can't turn off scrolling in GridView.

Anyhow, the solution is for getView() in each GridView's adapter to set the *button* heights to the value that makes them all fit exactly in the height allocated to the GridView. I actually tried that before posting here, but used the construct:

btn.setHeight(number);

instead of setting the height in the button's layout parameters. That was due to my not realizing that the button height doesn't get set until after the layout has completed. Also, I hadn't considered getting the usable screen height so I could compute a device-independent height. Sorry for being new to this stuff.

I spent a lot of time trying to use the height of the LinearLayout that contains the GridViews, which would reduce the number of constants I need to adjust for different device sizes. But that got very messy due to timing of layout completion and the oddities of how tabbed fragments are implemented (and yes, I tried setting up an OnGlobalLayoutListener). Bottom line, there are some timing issues with that approach. The upshot was that the keypad area would disappear for a second or two and get redrawn when the fragment was tabbed into view after being destroyed and re-created. It can probably be done, but I didn't have time to figure it out.

Anyhow, here are the relevant additions to the code. First I added the following method that I found here to the MainActivity:

```
    // Method to get the usable screen height and width, which will then be available through their getters and setters

private void setUsableScreenDimensions() {
    DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float screen_w = dm.widthPixels;
    float screen_h = dm.heightPixels;

    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resId > 0) {
        screen_h -= getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resId);
    }
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    if(getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, typedValue, true)){
        screen_h -= getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(typedValue.resourceId);
    }       
    screenWidth = (double) screen_w;
    screenHeight = (double) screen_h;
}
```

Then I added this code to the adapter constructor:

```
    double keypadParentHeight = (MainActivity.getScreenHeight() * Constants.KEYPAD_PARENT_HEIGHT_PERCENTAGE);
    double rowHeight = keypadParentHeight / Constants.NUMBER_OF_KEYPAD_ROWS;        
    buttonHeight = (int) (rowHeight * Constants.BUTTON_HEIGHT_FACTOR);
```

Finally, the button height in getView is set thusly:

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, buttonHeight);
LayoutParams params = params;
```

The actual code is slightly more complicated because there are two sets of keys (two GridViews) with different weights (1:2), so the button sizes are different. In addition, the same keypads are drawn by the same adapter on three different fragments with different size parent LinearLayouts. But that all boiled down to a few extra constants and some conditional statements in the adapter.